# use two jquery uploadify scripts

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Is it possible to use two uploadify scripts in one page?

When first script finishes uploading data, then second one should start.

Is this possible?

...................

sorry that is not explained clearly.

I wish have two uploadify script in one page. One uploadify script upload only images, second only pdf files.

Comment: What do you mean by "start second"? Does the user select two files? Please add more detail

Comment: I'm confused, did you read the section in the [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) about the queue, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Have you tried "uploadifying" the element on the OnComplete of the first one?

Answer (score 1):

To use two or more [Upladify](http://uploadify.com/) instances, each of them must have an unique ID (not class!).

```
$('#upload_1').uploadify({ ... });
$('#upload_2').uploadify({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file_kpi_36" name="file_kpi_36" class="inputFileUploadify"/>
```

when the number 36 is dinamical!

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inputFileUploadify").each(function() {
        var myID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + myID).uploadify({
            'uploader'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'        : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg'     : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'expressInstall': '/uploadify/expressInstall.swf',
            'folder'        : '/uploads',
            'displayData'   : 'percentage',
            'method'        : 'post',
            'simUploadLimit': 1,
            'queueSizeLimit': 1,
            'sizeLimit' :    10485760,
            'auto'          : true
        });
    });
});
```

try and you see! ;)